# Parse JSON correctly for table view cell

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I'm parsing JSON from my API which works fine but every time I select a row and get to the detail view he shows me the product with is supposed to be linked to the product shown at the very bottom. I don't understand why it isn't parsing the product id for the specific row because I have set it to parse for `indexPath.row`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *neuheitenCell = @"neuheitenCell";
    CJHomeTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:neuheitenCell];

    wareID = [[arrayArtikelWareID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"ware_id"];
    NSLog(@"Waren ID: %@", wareID);

    cell.artikelName.text = [[arrayArtikelName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.artikelHersteller.text = [[arrayArtikelHersteller objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"lieferant_name"];


    return cell;

}
```

**EDIT:

```
-(void) parseJSONWithURL: (NSURL *) jsonURL {

    dispatch_async(mainThreadQueue, ^{
        NSError *error = nil;

        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

        NSString *json =[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

        if (error == nil) {


            NSData *jsonData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            dictionaryNewStuff = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            if (error == nil) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    arrayNeuheiten = [[dictionaryNewStuff valueForKey:@"newstuff"] valueForKey:@"Neuheiten"];
                    arrayArtikelBild = [[dictionaryNewStuff valueForKey:@"newstuff"] valueForKey:@"Neuheiten"];
                    [neuheitenTableView reloadData];
                    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
                });
            }

        }
    });

}
```

JSON can be viewed at my [API](http://www.myclassico.com/app.php)
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you getting any error, variables are nil...what is the problem?

Comment: no I don't. I actually get the ids but they are in the wrong order.

Comment: well not in the wrong order but I just don't get the id I want for the specific row. I always get the one for last cell which was loaded (the one at the very bottom)

Comment: could you please show us json itself ?

Comment: Can you check that in your arrays the value are well ordered?

Comment: how do you parse the JSON?

Comment: @ogres what do you mean by json itself. The parsing logic or the json I parse

Comment: @Alex if I understand you correctly then yeah.

Comment: json you parse and data you want to show , also ordering please , and you are not using wareID in this code , why do you need this line     wareID = [[arrayArtikelWareID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"ware_id"];
    NSLog(@"Waren ID: %@", wareID); ?

Comment: It's a product ID with gets pushed to a detail view controller and with this id all the product information are parsed in the detail view controller. I use it in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @ogres I linked to my API in my post

Comment: You copy the json to arrayNeuheiten and arrayArtikelBild. Why do you have two arrays with the same information? And also, where do you set arrayArtikelHersteller and arrayArtikelName?

Comment: @Alex look at my API. is posted a link to it in my post at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using following code ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *neuheitenCell = @"neuheitenCell";
    CJHomeTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:neuheitenCell];

    NSDictionary *object = [arrayNeuheiten objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *wareID = [object objectForKey:@"ware_id"];
    NSLog(@"Waren ID: %@", wareID);

    cell.artikelName.text = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.artikelHersteller.text = [object objectForKey:@"lieferant_name"];


    return cell;
}
```

Why do you need two arrays for holding the data ? I mean following lines  " arrayNeuheiten = [[dictionaryNewStuff valueForKey:@"newstuff"] valueForKey:@"Neuheiten"]; arrayArtikelBild = [[dictionaryNewStuff valueForKey:@"newstuff"] valueForKey:@"Neuheiten"]; "

Also where do you assign anything to arrayArtikelWareID ,arrayArtikelName ,arrayArtikelHersteller

Comment: That's the same I told him in the comment. The problem should be there

Comment: are you sure ? and what is the exact problem ? try NSLog(@"%@",object); and see which objects are retrieved during this method

Comment: "aktionspreis_global" = "0.00";
    bild = "http://www.myclassico.com/img/shop/14393_1_detail.jpg";
    farben = 1;
    gruppe = "M\U00fctzen & H\U00fcte";
    "gruppe_id" = 27;
    "gruppe_rubrik" = Accessoires;
    "gruppe_url" = "Muetzen-Huete";
    "lieferant_name" = Deginther;
    "lieferant_url" = Deginther;
    "menge_bestellbar" = 18;
    mwst = 19;
    name = "Strickm\U00fctze mit Bommel";
    "name_url" = "Strickmuetze-mit-Bommel";
    neu = 1;
    position = 89;
    preis = "89.00";
    sale = 0;
    verpackungsservice = ja;
    "ware_id" = 14393;

Comment: well its not the same. Its getting parsed correctly now but it still opens not in the correct order

Comment: What is the correct order? Because now, cell 0 has element at index 0 no? Maybe you can check indexPath

Comment: You should order it on the server side , NSArray will hold its order as it is in the NSDictionary json , so sort it on the server or you could also use NSSortDescriptor to sort an array then use it in the tableview

Comment: @Alex yeah that's what I expected but now if I hit any cell in the table view it opens the product with the product id on the cell which was parsed last.

Comment: Ok, that's a different problem. Do you have prepareForSegueMethod? And do you have didSelectRowAtIndexPath? If you have them, please show them.
I guess when you touch a cell, you are a passing the ID to the newViewcontroller, don't you?